# Python session, cookies, and the web 

Tags: python, forms, session, cookies, mechanize

** **edit 
after a short thought, I just figured that I don't have to use mechanize at all
and yet I don't know which Python library I should use in order to interact w/ 
cookies and session data, 
can anyone please hint me ?** **

I would like to perform a simple login and use the credentials ( and cookies, session data too ) for some site.

I used mechanize in order to perform the basic form usage, since the form is being built using Javascript

```
import cookielib
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)


br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

parameters = { 'username' : 'w00t',
               'password' : 't00w'
            }
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
resp = br.open(url,data)
```

however for some reason I can't seem to get any positive response from the server, I don't see any sign (for ex redirection to the desired page) , nor I know how to continue once I have the cookies and session to actually continue using these cookies and session data

I was wondering if anyone could hint me or refer me to the correct documentation, as what I have found does not seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) for this sort of thing in Python before. I found it very straight forward and to have great documentation. Here's an example that includes cookies in a request:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')

>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
>>> r.text
'{"cookies": {"cookies_are": "working"}}'
```

I have used Mechanize and if I recall, it keeps track of cookies for you. To the contrary, this library will require you to constantly repost the cookies upon requests.